# Get Google Email Using Azure AD user credentials

Tags: azure, google-oauth, azure-active-directory, sharepoint-apps

we are creating app which will be hosted on SharePoint Site. we have builded trust between google for works and azure AD. now we want to access Google email using current user credentials (without inputting username and password). we are using provider hosted apps and .net platform. can anyone help with this. So can you help me with how to access gmail account with credentials of azure ad ?

Comment: Welcome to stack I think you have forgotten the question part of your question.   you might want to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You will need to show us what you have done so far to solve your problem.   Help me access X is to broad you need to show us what you are working on and any issues you are having and we can help with that.   As it is an answer for your question would be us doing it for you and would be to long for this format.